# Trying to split string into single words or "quoted words", and want to keep the quotes in the resulting array

Tags: ruby, regex, csv

I'm trying to split a string like `Presentation about "Test Driven Development"` into an array like this:

```
[ 'Presentation',
  'about',
  '"Behavior Driven Development"' ]
```

I have tried `CSV::parse_line(string, col_sep: ' ')`, but this results in

```
[ 'Presentation',
  'about',
  'Behavior Driven Development' ] # I'm missing the quotes here
```

I also tried some regexp magic, but I'm still a beginner and didn't succeed. I guess this is quite simple for a pro, so maybe someone could point me into the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: I fixed my answer. It should work for you now.

Comment: Ha! CSV was actually exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You may use the following regular expression [`split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#method-i-split):

```
str = 'Presentation about "Test Driven Development"'
p str.split(/\s(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)/)
# => ["Presentation", "about", "\"Test Driven Development\""]
```

It splits if there is a space but only if the text following until the end contains an even number of `"`. Be aware that this version will only work if all your strings are properly quoted.

An alternative solution uses [`scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan) to read the parts of the string (besides spaces):

```
p str.scan(/(?:\w|"[^"]*")+/)
# => ["Presentation", "about", "\"Test Driven Development\""]
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm! Regexes are magic... I will try to dissect them and understand it.

Comment: For your reference, I used this to remove empty elements and strip quotes and spaces: 

"a   b 'c d '".split(/\s(?=(?:[^'"]|'[^']*'|"[^"]*")*$)/).select {|s| not s.empty? }.map {|s| s.gsub(/(^ +)|( +$)|(^["']+)|(["']+$)/,'')}

Answer (score 4):

Just to extend the previous answer from Howard, you can add this method:

```
class String
  def tokenize
    self.
      split(/\s(?=(?:[^'"]|'[^']*'|"[^"]*")*$)/).
      select {|s| not s.empty? }.
      map {|s| s.gsub(/(^ +)|( +$)|(^["']+)|(["']+$)/,'')}
  end
end
```

And the result:

```
> 'Presentation      about "Test Driven Development"  '.tokenize
=> ["Presentation", "about", "Test Driven Development"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
"Presentation about \"Test Driven Development\"".scan(/\s?\w+\s?|"[\w\s]*"/).map {|s| s.strip}
```

Comment: Fine, removed my -1. Please note that now the spaces are included in the result.

Comment: What about `.scan(/(?:\S|"[^"]*")+/)`?

Comment: Thank you! It's interesting how many different ways there are to attack a problem.