# How to bundle multiple static files as zip archive for download

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

My Jekyll page is meant to provide sample solutions for a coding book's exercises.
The solutions are a bunch of .cpp files (C++ code files) stored in a folder inside my Jekyll project so that I can open the same folder in an IDE.

I've managed to auto-generate one page per book chapter which displays the relevant solutions as a list of code blocks (one per each exercise). I do that by looping through `site.static_files` and identifying the files by numbers in their filenames (e.g. two solutions for chapter 1: `01_1_FirstSolution.cpp`, `01_2_SecondSolution.cpp`)

Now, I want to also provide a zip archive per book chapter containing the relevant .cpp files. I don't want to make the zip file manually because then I would not be able to simply change one of the code files anymore. Ideally, I would like to build a zip file while looping through `site.static_files` and filtering for the relevant files.

When searching for this, I mainly found speed-optimization plugins for bundling and compressing assets. I am running Jekyll on Windows.

Comment: once you coment something on the existing answers, i will do some research.

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez I did so :-)

Comment: and you have already granted the bounty too, cool.

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez sorry, the grace period was nearing its end and I didn't want the points to go to the waste. The answer I awarded had an interesting twist so it deserved it. I have not accepted an answer because the problem has not yet been solved. If you have an alternative approach, feel free to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [jekyll-zip-bundler](https://hasper.info/jekyll-zip-bundler/) plugin for this.

### How it is used

Filenames as multiple parameters:

`{% zip archiveToCreate.zip file1.txt file2.txt %}`

Spaces in filenames:

`{% zip archiveToCreate.zip file1.txt folder/file2.txt 'file with spaces.txt' %}`

A variable to contain a list of files is also possible:

`{% zip ziparchiveToCreate.zip {{ chapter_code_files }} %}`

### The plugin code

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

# Copyright 2021 by Philipp Hasper
# MIT License
# https://github.com/PhilLab/jekyll-zip-bundler

require 'jekyll'
require 'zip'
# ~ gem 'rubyzip', '~>2.3.0'

module Jekyll
  # Valid syntax:
  # {% zip archiveToCreate.zip file1.txt file2.txt %}
  # {% zip archiveToCreate.zip file1.txt folder/file2.txt 'file with spaces.txt' %}
  # {% zip {{ variableName }} file1.txt 'folder/file with spaces.txt' {{ otherVariableName }} %}
  # {% zip {{ variableName }} {{ VariableContainingAList }} %}
  class ZipBundlerTag < Liquid::Tag
    VARIABLE_SYNTAX = /[^{]*(\{\{\s*[\w\-.]+\s*(\|.*)?\}\}[^\s{}]*)/mx.freeze
    CACHE_FOLDER = '.jekyll-cache/zip_bundler/'

    def initialize(tag_name, markup, tokens)
      super
      # Split by spaces but only if the text following contains an even number of '
      # Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/11566264
      # Extended to also not split between the curly brackets of Liquid
      # In addition, make sure the strings are stripped and not empty
      @files = markup.strip.split(/\s(?=(?:[^'}]|'[^']*'|{{[^}]*}})*$)/)
                     .map(&:strip)
                     .reject(&:empty?)
    end

    def render(context)
      # First file is the target zip archive path
      target, files = resolve_parameters(context)
      abort 'zip tag must be called with at least two files' if files.empty?

      zipfile_path = CACHE_FOLDER + target
      FileUtils.makedirs(File.dirname(zipfile_path))

      # Create the archive. Delete file, if it already exists
      File.delete(zipfile_path) if File.exist?(zipfile_path)
      Zip::File.open(zipfile_path, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
        files.each do |file|
          # Two arguments:
          # - The name of the file as it will appear in the archive
          # - The original file, including the path to find it
          zipfile.add(File.basename(file), file)
        end
      end
      puts "Created archive #{zipfile_path}"

      # Add the archive to the site's static files
      site = context.registers[:site]
      site.static_files << Jekyll::StaticFile.new(site, "#{site.source}/#{CACHE_FOLDER}",
                                                  File.dirname(target),
                                                  File.basename(zipfile_path))
      # No rendered output
      ''
    end

    def resolve_parameters(context)
      # Resolve the given parameters to a file list
      target, files = @files.map do |file|
        next file unless file.match(VARIABLE_SYNTAX)

        # This is a variable. Look it up.
        context[file]
      end

      [target, files]
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('zip', Jekyll::ZipBundlerTag)
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's possible to get content of your files ([*fetch*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) etc.) you may use [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) library to pack them in Zip. I'm not sure that this fits for you in jekyll... but i would try doing like this.

To try an example just create an html file or [open my example with fetch](https://daniil-loban.github.io/jsZipExample/index.html).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.6.0/jszip.min.js" integrity="sha512-uVSVjE7zYsGz4ag0HEzfugJ78oHCI1KhdkivjQro8ABL/PRiEO4ROwvrolYAcZnky0Fl/baWKYilQfWvESliRA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script type="module" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.0/FileSaver.min.js" integrity="sha512-csNcFYJniKjJxRWRV1R7fvnXrycHP6qDR21mgz1ZP55xY5d+aHLfo9/FcGDQLfn2IfngbAHd8LdfsagcCqgTcQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var zip = new JSZip();
    zip.file("Hello.txt", "Hello World\n");
    zip.file("Hello2.txt", "Hello2 World\n");
    //var img = zip.folder("images");
    //img.file("smile.gif", imgData, {base64: true});
    zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
    .then((content) => {
        // see FileSaver.js
        saveAs(content, "example.zip");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe a Ruby zip library would be better suited here, to generate the archive at Jekyll bundle time. However, doing it on-the-fly in Javascript as a last resort is also interesting

Comment: @PhilLab  I think same, If you can skip any runtime work, skip it =) I used this lib for my code generator...

Comment: @PhilLab If you allow your customers select files (by checkbox like in email) This is  good way too.

Answer (score 1):

Jekyll is a primarily static website builder, so perhaps it'd be ideal to run a program or shell scripts before building with Jekyll and have them output to the `site.static_files` location you wish to output to as above.

You could use a script before running Jekyll, to zip your files and then run the Jekyll build process.

There are also [Generator plugins](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/generators/) which you could write to achieve similar results, using either the plugin, or Ruby's `system` commands to run scripts as part of your build.

Comment: Is there a standard way to execute scripts as part of the jekyll build process? If I could also use the Jekyll way of enumerating the static files `{% for file in site.static_files %} {% if file.path contains '/somesubfolder/' %}`, this would be beautiful- though absolutely not a necessity, as I could use `ls` in the scripts anyway

Comment: You could use Generator plugins to run "system" commands it seems. [jekyll docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/generators/) While I couldn't find much info on the docs, [this issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1433) shows it can be done. Obviously this means running system commands from the Ruby plugin.